# True False value

Tags: python, if-statement, debugging, boolean

Why python considering the false value as a true even though I am sure its False it keeps implement the"if True:" statement

I write

```
2+3 == 2
If True :
  Print("yes")
If False :
  Print("no")
```

I expected no but it's yes

What is the problem?!

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements The conditional goes after the if, not before it.

Comment: Python is considering `True` as `True`, not `False`. You are fundamentally misunderstanding the syntax of an `if` statement

Comment: You have a basic misunderstanding of how `if` works.  `if True` does _not_ refer to the outcome of the previous expression.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking amiss. In the IF statements, you have to express the condition that you want to check.

```
if 2+3 == 2:
  print("yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

An IF statement automatically checks if the condition is TRUE. So, **no need for it to be**:

```
if (2+3 == 2) == True:
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in an `if` statement comes after the `if`.  For example:

```
wheels_on_vehicle = 2            # assign 2 to the variable motorcycle

if wheels_on_vehicle == 2:       # check if the variable is equal to 2
    print("motorcycle")          # if so, print "motorcycle"

else:                            # otherwise,
    print("not a motorcycle")    # print "not a motorcycle"
```

Note: we don't have to check whether the condition equals `true` or `false` explicitly.  The result of the conditional expression is already a boolean (T/F) which is exactly what the `if` statement needs

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion expression (2+3 == 2) is outside your 'if' statement. When you run 2+3 == 2 in a Python command line interface (REPL) it outputs False, as you well asserted and expected. So Python has not considered to be True an assertion that is False. When in doubt, in such short blocks of code as this example, try it out using REPL.